# Winload.exe startup issues on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot

I'm trying to get my computer up and running after my mouse and keyboard stopped working in Windows 10. Numlock, Sroll lock and Caps lock lights wouldn't turn on and mouse wouldn't move at all (corded mouse). I tried fixing it uninstalling an update through a recovery media and ended up doing a lot more damage. Now my computer won't boot because my winload.exe is missing or corrupt. When I try run `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=E: /offwindir=E:\Windows` I get a message saying "Windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation. I've rebuilt my bcd and ran `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` successfully.
Other similiar questions say "run chkdsk /r and reboot your computer and you're good to go". Well, not in my case. I've checked that my USB recovery media is running same version as my installed Windows v. 10.0.18362.239

Any ideas of how to get it working?

Comment: You did too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do a Repair if Windows is running and it is not. Probably fastest at this point is to boot with a bootable USB operating system and recover the data. Then use the recovery USB key to reinstall Windows